# Unity 5.2.3 - unable to build to iOS for 3 months now

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, il2cpp

I have to update a game already live on App Store using Unity 5.2.3.

I have been getting a lot of il2cpp related errors due to which I cannot build anymore for iOS....this has been going on for 3 months now....have tried all Unity versions from 5.1.2 to 5.2.3....as you can imagine it has not been good for our business.

Have earlier posted this issue on Unity forums and posted Bug reports as well but still no solution has been found for this issue.

Am again posting these errors which come up at the time of building for iOS within Unity3D:

```
ERROR 1/4:
```

> IL2CPP error (no further information about what managed code was being
>   converted is available) Additional information: Build a development
>   build for more information. Failed to resolve assembly: '…project
>   path… (On Dec 09, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

```
ERROR 2/4:
```

> Failed running /Applications/Unity
>   5.2.3/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --copy-level=None --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --extra-types.file="/Applications/Unity 5.2.3/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/il2cpp_default_extra_types.txt"
>   --assembly="…project path… /Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll"
>   --assembly…project path… /Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll" --assembly…project
>   path… /Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll"
>   --assembly="…project path… /Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll"
>   --generatedcppdir="…project path… /Temp/il2cppOutput/il2cppOutput"
>
> stdout: IL2CPP error (no further information about what managed code
>   was being converted is available) Additional information: Build a
>   development build for more information. Failed to resolve assembly:
>   '…project path…  (On Dec 09, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception:
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly:
>   '…project path…  (On Dec 09, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'   at Unity.IL2CPP.Common.AssemblyLoader.Resolve
>   (IMetadataScope scope) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Common.AssemblyLoader.Load (System.String name) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0
>   (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator10`2[System.String,Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[AssemblyDefinition] (IEnumerable`1
>   source) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.CollectAssembliesToConvert () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies (System.String[]
>   assemblies, NiceIO.NPath outputDir) [0x00000] in :0 
>   stderr:
>
> Unhandled Exception: Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to
>   resolve assembly: '…project path…  (On Dec 09, Version=0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'   at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Common.AssemblyLoader.Resolve (IMetadataScope scope)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Common.AssemblyLoader.Load (System.String name) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0
>   (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator10`2[System.String,Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[AssemblyDefinition] (IEnumerable`1
>   source) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.CollectAssembliesToConvert () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies (System.String[]
>   assemblies, NiceIO.NPath outputDir) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly:
>   '…project path… (On Dec 09, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'   at Unity.IL2CPP.Common.AssemblyLoader.Resolve
>   (IMetadataScope scope) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.Common.AssemblyLoader.Load (System.String name) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter+c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0
>   (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator10`2[System.String,Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[AssemblyDefinition] (IEnumerable`1
>   source) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.CollectAssembliesToConvert () [0x00000]
>   in :0    at Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.Apply ()
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Unity.IL2CPP.AssemblyConverter.ConvertAssemblies (System.String[]
>   assemblies, NiceIO.NPath outputDir) [0x00000] in :0
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String,
>   CompilerOutputParserBase) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:68)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(ICollection`1,
>   String, String) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:417)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:301)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String,
>   IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:218)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

```
ERROR 3/4:
```

> Exception: /Applications/Unity
>   5.2.3/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly! UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram
>   (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String
>   workingDirectory,
>   UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:70)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (ICollection`1
>   userAssemblies, System.String outputDirectory, System.String
>   workingDirectory) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:417)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:301)
>   UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder,
>   System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider
>   platformProvider, System.Action`1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile,
>   UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:218)
>   UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess
>   (UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor pp, BuildTarget target,
>   System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea,
>   System.String stagingAreaDataManaged, System.String playerPackage,
>   System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String
>   productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
>   usedClassRegistry) UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess
>   (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
>   UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target,
>   System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String
>   productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String
>   downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl,
>   BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry
>   usedClassRegistry) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
>   UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

```
ERROR 4/4:
```

> Error building Player: Exception: /Applications/Unity
>   5.2.3/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

I need help on this issue, or else we may have to abandon this project, and make future games projects using other game engines!

Comment: Could you share something about your project? Plugins ? libraries? You could try to remove those one by one so that you know what asset is causing the problem.

Comment: I think this error happens before the project gets to XCode. The problem is during the code conversion from IL -> C++ code done by il2cpp.exe. This looks like the same issue reported on the Unity forums here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-2-3-unable-to-build-to-ios-for-3-months-now.372726

Comment: @Josh Peterson Yes this problem happens when I build for iOS in Unity, no Xcode file gets created.

Comment: The strange thing is, when I create a new project and then build for iOS, no il2cpp errors come up during that time, i.e. Unity is able to create the Xcode file...

Comment: @user2442902 It may be best to submit a bug report to Unity then. This should not be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a long answer for other developers may find it helpful. You should go the the bottom case.

I do not know what the problem is. I do updates of the old games too and get a lot of weird errors. Most of the cases I can not append the existing x32 xCode project (mostly due to lack of my iOS experience, less so for the speed of making a new xCode project). So:

**Make sure you dropped all the x32 plugins, or updated them**

Old games most probably are using x32 plugins like Etcetera or Prime31... These may stop ill2cpp from compiling. Update them if possible to x64 or drop them and write your own implementation in Objective C or Swift.

**Make a new xCode project**

Not necessary but if you are lazy like me you should. This is mainly due to switch to ill2cpp build. Build a whole new xCode project with ill2cpp and try to transfer all the changes you did to the old xCode project to this one. Alternatively you can append the old project but make sure you know how the ill2cpp project is structured in xCode as well as have some basic experience with project settings and iOS in general.

**Make a new Unity Project**

This is a last resort. If you use version control system it will probably go crazy. Anyways - if the above steps do not work you'd have to try this - make a new folder to store a new project; copy the Assets and Project Settings folders to the new folder; open the new folder as a project in Unity (Unity will complain a bit about missing files but will re-create project for you). Then again do the **Make a new xCode project** step.

Hope it helps.

Comment: is it possible to write iOS plugins for Unity in Swift ?

Comment: never tried. as for today probably you'd have to write a bridge to objective C. but everything's being transferred to swift these days.